# I am trying to identify a time slip SF short story where a woman drives into the future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I am trying to identify a short story. My roommate told me about it, and I want to identify it so that I can read it myself. I don't know what happens in the end of the story. My roommate does not remember where he read it, who the author is or what the title was.

An old woman drives her truck down a road, and somehow ends up in the future. There, she sells junks in the back of her truck (old toasters etc.). As she is the only one who can supply the future people with her junk, she makes good business, making a few trips back and forth.
Then the old lady finds out about spaceships that future people were building. Realizing that if the spaceships are completed, the people will leave, and the old lady will lose business, she decides to sabotage the space travel.

Comment: Interesting story. Could you or your mate check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog their memory?

Comment: I have a vague memory of this storyline, but I can't recall where I read it either.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [Captive Market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_Market_(short_story)) by [Philip K. Dick](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?23).

> In it, an old woman uses her ability to travel through time to exploit a special market - a group of survivors in a post-apocalyptic world, struggling to repair a rocket to take them to Venus.

Comment: Good. The story is available at https://archive.org/stream/1955-04_IF#page/n89/mode/2up